# Toggle Google Chart series within Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-visualization

Just starting with Angular. I need to incorporate Google Charts into an Angular app.
Found [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/3RJ2HS?p=preview) (code posted in snippet below), illustrating how to use Google Charts within a directive:

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <title>
        Google Chart Tools AngularJS Directive Example
    </title>
</head>
<body ng-app="google-chart-example" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<h1>Google Chart Tools AngularJS Directive Example</h1>
<p>This is probably the most simple example you can get.  It
  just shows you what you need to get the Google Chart Tools AngularJS Directive to work.
</p>

<div>
<div google-chart chart="chart" style="{{chart.cssStyle}}"/>
</div>

<p>
  Here are the steps:
  <ol>
    <li>Download <a href="https://raw.github.com/bouil/angular-google-chart/gh-pages/ng-google-chart.js">ng-google-chart.js from github</a> and add a script tag to your html.</li>
    <li>Create a div like: <b><pre ng-non-bindable> &lt;div google-chart chart=&quot;chart&quot; style=&quot;{{chart.cssStyle}}&quot;/&gt;</pre></b></li>
    <li>Add 'googlechart' to your module like this: <b><pre>angular.module('myApp',[ 'googlechart', ...</pre></b></li>
    <li>Populate the <b>$scope.chart</b> like this:</li>
  </ol>
  <pre>{{chart | json}}</pre>
</p>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://bouil.github.io/angular-google-chart/ng-google-chart.js"></script>
<script src="example.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

One of my requirements is to enable users to toggle visibility of an individual chart series on and off, either by clicking on the corresponding legend, or in some similar way.

I also found this [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/6gz2Q/60/) of toggling visibility on and off outside of Angular:

```js
function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'x');
    data.addColumn('number', 'y1');
    data.addColumn('number', 'y2');
    data.addColumn('number', 'y3');
    // add random data
    var y1 = 50, y2 = 50, y3 = 50;
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        y1 += Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) * Math.pow(-1, Math.floor(Math.random() * 2));
        y2 += Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) * Math.pow(-1, Math.floor(Math.random() * 2));
        y3 += Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) * Math.pow(-1, Math.floor(Math.random() * 2));
        data.addRow([i, y1, y2, y3]);
    }
    
    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    
    // create columns array
    var columns = [];
    // display these data series by default
    var defaultSeries = [1, 3];
    var series = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
        if (i == 0 || defaultSeries.indexOf(i) > -1) {
            // if the column is the domain column or in the default list, display the series
            columns.push(i);
        }
        else {
            // otherwise, hide it
            columns.push({
                label: data.getColumnLabel(i),
                type: data.getColumnType(i),
                sourceColumn: i,
                calc: function () {
                    return null;
                }
            });
        }
        if (i > 0) {
            columns.push({
                calc: 'stringify',
                sourceColumn: i,
                type: 'string',
                role: 'annotation'
            });
            // set the default series option
            series[i - 1] = {};
            if (defaultSeries.indexOf(i) == -1) {
                // backup the default color (if set)
                if (typeof(series[i - 1].color) !== 'undefined') {
                    series[i - 1].backupColor = series[i - 1].color;
                }
                series[i - 1].color = '#CCCCCC';
            }
        }
    }
    
    var options = {
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        series: series
    }
    
    function showHideSeries () {
        var sel = chart.getSelection();
        // if selection length is 0, we deselected an element
        if (sel.length > 0) {
            // if row is undefined, we clicked on the legend
            if (sel[0].row == null) {
                var col = sel[0].column;
                if (typeof(columns[col]) == 'number') {
                    var src = columns[col];
                    
                    // hide the data series
                    columns[col] = {
                        label: data.getColumnLabel(src),
                        type: data.getColumnType(src),
                        sourceColumn: src,
                        calc: function () {
                            return null;
                        }
                    };
                    
                    // grey out the legend entry
                    series[src - 1].color = '#CCCCCC';
                }
                else {
                    var src = columns[col].sourceColumn;
                    
                    // show the data series
                    columns[col] = src;
                    series[src - 1].color = null;
                }
                var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
                view.setColumns(columns);
                chart.draw(view, options);
            }
        }
    }
    
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', showHideSeries);
    
    // create a view with the default columns
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns(columns);
    chart.draw(view, options);
}

google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>

<div id="creativeCommons" style="text-align: center; width: 400px;">
    <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/deed.en_US"><img alt="Creative Commons License" style="border-width:0" src="http://i.creativecommons.org/l/by-nc-sa/3.0/88x31.png" /></a><br /><span xmlns:dct="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" href="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/InteractiveResource" property="dct:title" rel="dct:type">Code to turn on or off data series by clicking on legend entries</span> by <span xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" property="cc:attributionName">Andrew Gallant</span> is licensed under a <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/deed.en_US">Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported License</a>.
</div>
```

I'm so terribly inexperienced with JavaScript, I do not know how to combine the two, to end up with a directive, which would include this visibility toggle feature.
If anyone knows how this is done, I would really be grateful.

Comment: I formatted the links in your post and added the code from your plunk and JSFiddle. Next time, please add them yourself. You can use the "Code snippet" button when posting or editing your question (Ctrl + M if you like keyboard shortcuts) to add the snippets.

Comment: Your answer was link-only, it contained no useful information besides the link, @Eugene. Such answers are considered to have unacceptably low quality and are routinely deleted on [SO], because the link may break anytime and people want to find answers, not links to possible answers. You should edit your answer to include the code and its explanation, in as simple version as possible. It need not be a fully functioning code, the main idea explanation and pseudocode are enough. Then your answer can be undeleted.